# Make singed .ipa with buildozer

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to make an .ipa file for my iPad using Kivy, Python and Buildozer. I looked into the .spec file and found an option called `ios.codesign.allowed` and `iOS.codesign.debug`. After a few minutes of research I found out that I can only install signed ipa files since my device is not jailbroken. (But I am not sure if if I actually cannot…)

So I didn‘t actually try to install the app on my iPad, because as soon as I install it, I want it to actually work… So what I would like to know is the following: Can I make a signed ipa with buildozer (on GitHub Actions) without having to buy a paid apple developer account? If not, can I still install the app file WITHOUT a jailbreak? Is there some way to „trick“ buildozer into making a signed ipa without me needing to pay anything?
If I need to sign the code, how can I find out what to put into `iOS.codesign.debug` and do I have to put anything else into the buildozer.spec file?
Thanks for answering

Also, I‘m sorry if my English is bad…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use appdb or Scarlet but you will likely get revoked, which is when Apple bans your device from using one free certificate, then you will have to wait for another free cert to come available, to avoid revokes you can use Altstore which requires a computer and a **free** apple dev account or if your device supports it, use Trollstore.